# Iterator of a specific type - function argument - Metaprogramming

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to write a function that takes a (forward) iterator of a given type. It would be really helpful to use SFINAE. I came up with the following (not working) solution:

```
template<class ForwardIterator,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type, int>::value
    >::type
>
    inline void foo(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
{
}
```

In this case foo should be callable with `std::vector<int>::iterator` or just by providing raw int pointers. The problem is, it doesn't work as I've expected. The compiler (msvc 2019) always complains about not finding a matching overloaded function.

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Your are missing a default value for the `std::enable_if<>::type` parameter.

Comment: Do you only want to do this to avoid user calling `foo` with wrong iterators / objects, or do you needs SFINAE to choose between multiple `foo`s?

Comment: I just want to avoid the user from calling foo with wrong arguments.

Comment: @Neconspictor Using `static_assert` is probably a much easier way of achieving the same result in that case.

Comment: A default value for `std::enable_if<>::type` is `void`. That should be ok, isn't it?

Comment: @super : it works with a `static_assert` , but it would be better with SFINAE...

Comment: @Neconspictor As it is, SFINAE will give you pretty unreadable messages. SFINAE is interesting when you want to fall backs to something else when the "predicate" fails (hence the acronym). In the future, a better solution will be concepts, but as it is, a `static_assert` will probably be much clearer (custom explicit error message), and much easier to implement.

Comment: @Holt As I've already written to super, I preferred SFINAE over `static_assert` because you get instant feedback (you don't have to compile the code). But I see your point and `static_assert` is probably the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because if the `enable_if` gets a true value, your declaration would resolv to

```
template<class ForwardIterator, void>
```

This is not a valid way of declaring a template. If it instead said `class = void` it would have an unnamed parameter with a default value of void and it would work.

```
template<class ForwardIterator,
class = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type, int>::value
>::type>
```

This however comes with another issue. The default value of a template parameter is not part of it's signature. So if we try to add an overload where we replace `int` with `double` we would get an error due to the two template functions having the same signature.

To solve this second problem we instead make the second parameter a non-type parameter. This will make the signatures unique in respect to eachother.

```
template<class ForwardIterator,
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type, int>::value
>::type* = nullptr>
```

Now if the `enable_if` succeds, we get a `void*` non-type parameter with a default value of `nullptr` and we can add overloads with different requirements in our `enable_if` if we want to.

SFINAE is usually used to select between different functions depending on a criteria, if you only want to restrict the template `static_assert` is most likely the better option.

Easier to write, easier to read and you get a much more descriptive error message when compilation fails.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! The reason why I preferred SFINAE is, that the IDE marks it instantly as an error, if you use wrong input. But I see the points, why `static_assert` is the better option. So I will use it instead. But nevertheless, I learned something more about c++ :)